# Javascript - show TextField when select choice is

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, textfield

I'm new in JavaScript and I have following issue.

In my `HTML` code is ordinary `SELECT`

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I need to show `TextFied`  under the `SELECT` only when user select choice `Audi`.

```
<input type="text" name="something">
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: And you're not using jQuery, and the select does not have a ID, class or anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start using `JQuery` ([JQuery](http://jquery.com/)).

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // On Select option changed
    $("#someId").change(function(){
        // Check if current value is "audi"
        if($(this).val() === "audi"){
            // Show input field
            $("#textInputId").show();   //This changes display to block
        }else{
            // Hide input field
            $("#textInputId").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<select id="someId">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="text" style="display:none;" id="textInputId" name="someName"/>
```

Here is the example on JSFiddle:

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6dDLj/)

Comment: Yes sorry, changed it

Comment: Ok, i will look at JQuery...Your answer is the best, because it takes a effect when I change the choice back...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="txt" name="something">
```

And do something like this:

```
select.onchange=function(){
    if(select.value=="audi"){
       txt.type="text";    
    }
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/943xQ/

Comment: Be aware that some browsers (particularly IE, or perhaps only *old* IE) refuse to change the `type` property.

Comment: @Amit is it good practice to use id only `txt` for fetch text element, like you are not doing traditional way `document.getElementById('txt');` those are same thing?

Comment: @SumanBogati, when you declare a id, in html, it becomes a variable in js, whose properties you can use. No need to use getElementById if you already know the id of an element

Comment: Variables means it becomes the node which represent the particular element, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it easily using jquery like this:

here is the Html:

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="-1">Select One</option>  
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and text field:

```
<input type="text" name="something" id="txtCar" style="display:none;">

$('select#cars').change(function(){

if($(this).val() == "audi")
{
$('input#txtCar').show();
}

});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/su5U7/)

Comment: You don't deal with "Audi"

Comment: Where's the [tag:jquery] tag for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the bottom of the page (provided you already have included jquery into this page):

```
<script>
$('select').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 'audi') {
    $(this).parent().append('<input type="hidden" name="something">');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: That would append a second input field if you select the value "audi" a second time. I don't think he wants a hidden field, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the `onchange` event at `select` tag and can perform the action you want. Something like

**HTML**

```
<div id="result">
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
select.addEventListener("change", function() { 
if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'audi'){
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type="text";
        input.id="txt";
        input.name="something";

        document.getElementById('result').appendChild(input);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/943xQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Given the posted HTML, in which you use no specific identifiers (`class` or `id`) to identify the relevant elements, and given that you've not specified the availability of any JavaScript library, I'd suggest the following 'plain' JavaScript solution:

```
function showInputWhen(evt,val){
    var el = evt.target;
    el.nextElementSibling.style.display = el.value.toLowerCase() == val.toLowerCase() ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
};

var selectEl = document.querySelector('select');

selectEl.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    showInputWhen(e,'audi');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Bq7uy/).

References:

- [`ChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.nextElementSibling) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t84)</sup>.
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t13)</sup>.
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) <sup>[compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html#t30)</sup>.